# Does mongodb support action like spop in redis?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'am using python and new to mongo, I want to write a function to pop a document from a mongodb collection.It is fine to pop by first or random.I say 'pop' because I want to remove this document as it return.But I don't find such api in mongodb officual site, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#findandmodify-wrapper-sorted-remove) can handle it, pass `remove: true` and it would return a document before removing it:

```
db.people.findAndModify(
   {
     query: { state: "active" },
     sort: { rating: 1 },
     remove: true
   }
)
```

As of `pymongo`, use [`find_and_modify()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) method.

---

Demo:

```
> use foo
switched to db foo
> db.foo.insert({'test1': 1})
> db.foo.insert({'test2': 2})
> db.foo.insert({'test3': 3})
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af555f2067b54975678c"), "test1" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af5a5f2067b54975678d"), "test2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af5d5f2067b54975678e"), "test3" : 3 }
> db.foo.findAndModify({remove: true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af555f2067b54975678c"), "test1" : 1 }
> db.foo.findAndModify({remove: true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af5a5f2067b54975678d"), "test2" : 2 }
> db.foo.findAndModify({remove: true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9af5d5f2067b54975678e"), "test3" : 3 }
> db.foo.count()
0
```

Comment: I use startup_log for test. After I excute `db.startup_log.findAndModify({remove: true})`, `db.startup_log.count()` doesn't change.

Comment: @Mithril `.findAndModify()` needs the "query" portion even if blank. So `"query": {}` is required at the very least. The general purpose is to return the document that is "modified", either in it's original form as is the case without the "new" option as shown here, or adding "new" when updating changes to return the modified document. This is explained in the manual page link you were given.

Comment: @NeilLunn document says `query is Optional. The selection criteria for the modification`. So I don't need to add `query": {}`. And `db.startup_log.count()` doesn't change even if I add `query": {}`.

Comment: @Mithril it worked for me without the query, see the `Demo` section.

Comment: Your demo work very well.I also try some data myself, it seems I should not use `local.startup_log` which `findAndModify({remove: true})` do not work . Thank you very much.